# Font size when using non-Default style in Qt Quick Controls 2

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

When I use [any method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) to select one of non-*Default* (or *Base*) styles in *Qt Quick Controls 2* application (i.e. *Universal* or *Material*), then all the controls with text (like `Label`, `TextField`, whose font size must depend on `QGuiApplication::font`) uses font size value, which `QCoreApplication` has before changing:

```
QFont font = application.font();
bool ok = false;
font.setPointSize(QSettings{}.value("fontSize", 17).toInt(&ok));
Q_ASSERT(std::exchange(ok, false));
application.setFont(font);
```

Only `Text`, `TextField` are resized properly, but they are of no use in my GUI.

When I stick *Default* style, then all the mentioned items are resized properly.

How to make all the items be resized depending on global `font.pointSize` when used styles, other then *Default*?

Another connected question is how to get proper (means "contrast" and style-conformant) color for, say, highlighted text and background for the current style theme used? Using `SystemPalette { id: palette }` from `ApplicationWindow` in children gives colors suitable only for *Default* style (say `palette.highlightedText` is `"white"`, `palette.highlight` is `"blue"` or `"darkblue"` (not sure)). It looks ugly in style themes, differs from *Default*.

**Another important observation** is: if I set `font.pointSize: 17` (or equally `font: Qt.application.font`) in root `ApplicationWindow`, then all the items are resized properly, except of those of them which have new context: say, `highlight:` and `delegate:`s into `*View`s, `sourceComponent:`s into `Loader`s, default property item of `Component` and `Repeater` and others, where inheritance of the font breaks due to lost of the parent `Item`'s context.

It seems, that I should to manually "inherit" `ApplicationWindow.window.font` for each new context. It is sad if so. It is boring, if e.g. in `Repeater` I use `RowLayout` with a plenty of `Label`s: in each of `Label` I have to add `font: ApplicationWindow.window.font`.

Comment: did you ever find a good solution for this? I have hit the same problem.

Comment: @Colin nope. Seems there is need in ticket/bug report.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The workaround I came up with works pretty well but was a bit of work: create a custom qt quick controls (2!) style and copy over the qml for each element (TextField, etc). Then use your method to modify those files at the top and set the control's font to the application font.

Answer (score 0):

Orient, I know it is too late, but one can also set font size in `QApplication` like this:

```
QFont font = QApplication::font();
font.setPointSizeF(fontSize);
QApplication::setFont(font);
```

Comment: It is nonsense. *QML* application does not need `QApplication`, just `QGuiApplication`. There is [even a warning](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) to not to do as you mentioned.